# Tweepy - Limiting certain tweets

Tags: python, csv, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to get the below code to exclude any tweets that include restricted words from a list.  What is the best way to do this?

This code is also returning only the final tweet once i break out of the stream.  Is there a way to print all applicable tweets to CSV?

```
import sys
import tweepy
import csv

#pass security information to variables
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_key = ''
access_secret = ''


#use variables to access twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#create an object called 'customStreamListener'

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print (status.author.screen_name, status.created_at, status.text)
        # Writing status data
        with open('OutputStreaming.csv', 'w') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow([status.author.screen_name, status.created_at, status.text])


    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream

# Writing csv titles
with open('OutputStreaming.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['Author', 'Date', 'Text'])

streamingAPI = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
streamingAPI.filter(track=['Hasbro', 'Mattel', 'Lego'])
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Still hacking at it?

Comment: I think i m good here.  I got it to run but filtering maybe something I need to research further using a different package.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for the track parameter](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#track) in the Twitter API indicates that it is not possible to exclude terms from the filter, only to include words and phrases. You'll have to implement an additional filter inside your code to discard Tweets that contain words you don't want to include in your result set.

Comment: I guess that would be my real question.  What is the best way to implement this within the actual code above?

Comment: Inside on_status implement a check that looks at status.text and breaks out early before writing to the file if the text contains the words you are not interested in.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a look

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible exclude terms from the filter function, but you can implemented a custom selection.
Basically the idea is to check if the tweet's words contain not allowed words.
You can simply tokenize the tweet's text using [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/) module.

A simple example from nltk homepage:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> sentence = """At eight o'clock on Thursday morning
... Arthur didn't feel very good."""
>>> tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
>>> tokens
['At', 'eight', "o'clock", 'on', 'Thursday', 'morning',
'Arthur', 'did', "n't", 'feel', 'very', 'good', '.']
```

obliviously, in your case `sentence` is tweet.text.
So change your code in something similar to this:

```
def on_status(self, status):
    print (status.author.screen_name, status.created_at, status.text)
    is_allowed = True
    banned_words = ['word_1', 'word2', 'another_bad_word']
    words_text = nltk.word_tokenize(status.text)

    # loop banned_words and search if item is in words_text
    for word in banned_words:
        if word in words_text:
            # discard this tweet
            is_allowed = False
            break

    if is_allowed is True:
        # stuff for writing status data
        # ...
```

This code has not been tested, but shows you a way to reach your goal.

Let me know

Comment: Not familiar with how to use NLTK however is there some where to get a easier explanation on how to use than the documentation.